# Adicionar nome a Chave json

Tags: php, json

Nesse meu código a baixo ele me retorna json com a chave "serviços:"  porem não estou conseguindo colocar um nome   "Flight:"  na segunda chave.  como posso fazer com que essa chave seje nomeada

```
$final['servicos'] = [];
$fli['flight'] = [];

foreach($list as $t) {
 $data = new stdClass;

 $data->id = $t->id;
 $data->cliente = $t->comp_name;
 $data->pax = $t->firstName; 
 $data->phone = $t->phone;
 $data->origin = $t->origemida;
 $data->destiny = $t->destinoida;
 $data->status = $t->tra_status;
 $data->info = $t->comments;

 //voo Flight:
 $fli = new stdClass;
 $fli->flightNumber = $t->voo;
 $fli->flightCompany = $t->cia;
 $fli->flightEnd = $t->cia;
 $fli->flightGate = $t->voo;

array_push($final['servicos'], $data,$fli);

       }

 echo json_encode($final);
```

a Baixo segue minha saida json

```
{  
"servicos": [
{
  "id": 507,
  "cliente": "C2RIO OFFICE NITEROI",
  "pax": "Robert",
  "phone": "",
  "origin": "Airport GIG -RJ",
  "destiny": "Hotel Hilon Barra",
  "status": "3",
  "info": ""
},
  {
  "flightNumber": "GOL4568",
  "flightCompany": "GOL",
  "flightEnd": "GOL",
  "flightGate": "GOL4568"
  } ] }
```

Meu problema está aqui  teria que aparecer assim        Flight: {

```
   ???????{
  "flightNumber": "GOL4568",
  "flightCompany": "GOL",
  "flightEnd": "GOL",
  "flightGate": "GOL4568"
  } ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi a pergunta você quer adicionar um par `chave/valor` na representação JSON do objeto `$data`. Para fazer isso basta criar uma propriedade e passar o valor desejado.

```
<?php
$final = [];

$data = new stdClass;

$data->id = '507';
$data->cliente = 'C2RIO OFFICE NITEROI';
$data->pax = ''; 
$data->phone = 'Robert';
$data->origin = 'Airport GIG -RJ';
$data->destiny = 'Hotel Hilon Barra';
$data->status = '3';
$data->info = '';

//voo Flight:
$fli = new stdClass;
$fli->flightNumber = "GOL4568";
$fli->flightCompany = "GOL";
$fli->flightEnd = "GOL";
$fli->flightGate = "GOL4568";


$final['servicos'][] = $data; // Equivale a array_push($final['servicos'], $data);
$data->Flight = $fli; // Cria o par chave/valor desejado

echo json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Que vai resultar em:

```
{
    "servicos": {
        "id": "507",
        "cliente": "C2RIO OFFICE NITEROI",
        "pax": "",
        "phone": "Robert",
        "origin": "Airport GIG -RJ",
        "destiny": "Hotel Hilon Barra",
        "status": "3",
        "info": "",
        "Flight": {
            "flightNumber": "GOL4568",
            "flightCompany": "GOL",
            "flightEnd": "GOL",
            "flightGate": "GOL4568"
        }
    }
}
```

Ou então caso você queira que a representação JSON de `$final` seja um array com dois itens:

```
<?php
$final = [];

$data = new stdClass;

$data->id = '507';
$data->cliente = 'C2RIO OFFICE NITEROI';
$data->pax = ''; 
$data->phone = 'Robert';
$data->origin = 'Airport GIG -RJ';
$data->destiny = 'Hotel Hilon Barra';
$data->status = '3';
$data->info = '';

//voo Flight:
$fli = new stdClass;
$fli->flightNumber = "GOL4568";
$fli->flightCompany = "GOL";
$fli->flightEnd = "GOL";
$fli->flightGate = "GOL4568";

$final['servicos'][] = $data;
$final['Flight'][] = $fli;    

echo json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Que resulta em:

```
{
    "servicos": {
        "id": "507",
        "cliente": "C2RIO OFFICE NITEROI",
        "pax": "",
        "phone": "Robert",
        "origin": "Airport GIG -RJ",
        "destiny": "Hotel Hilon Barra",
        "status": "3",
        "info": ""
    },
    "Flight": {
        "flightNumber": "GOL4568",
        "flightCompany": "GOL",
        "flightEnd": "GOL",
        "flightGate": "GOL4568"
    }
}
```

Comment: ok era exatamente isso.... mais está afetando algo no loop.  só esta  fazendo um loop

Comment: @FabioHenrique faltou colocar um `[]` ao fazer o array push.

Comment: Perfeito funcionou perfeitamente obrigado

Answer (score -1):

```
 "Flight":[
{
  "flightNumber": "GOL4568",
  "flightCompany": "GOL",
  "flightEnd": "GOL",
  "flightGate": "GOL4568"
  }
 ] }
```

Comment: Gabriel, sua resposta pode ser útil, entretanto recomendo que explique-a melhor. Aconselho a fazer o  [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: è exatamente assim que queria... mais como fazer essa saida utilizando meu codigo acima